# Why does TFS "Remove Mapping" delete my files?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I wanted to check out an older version of the project in a different folder because I did not want to disturb my modified local content, so I thought I would just remove the mapping and map it to another folder and later map it back.

I was shocked to see that it started deleting my files!!! I quickly clicked cancel. Luckily it appears that it did not delete my modified and local files.

How am I supposed to do a thing like this?

This happened with Visual Studio 2010's Team Foundation Server, but I am sure it applies to all versions.

Comment: This behavior is normal for VS 2010 and TFS. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245474.aspx

Comment: I understand your pain in your title (and +1 for your frustration), but I felt the need to edit it because this kind of title isn't going to help your question be easily lookup-able down the road .

Comment: I just needed a moment to vent :-)

Comment: Jehof, one would think that "remove WORKSPACE" and "remove workspace MAPPING" would behave differently. Now I trust TFS even less.

Comment: Popular Question in eight months. Cool.

Comment: I just experience this problem!!!! TFS make me pain!! i uninstall the TFS and turn to SVN!

Comment: I used git for the past two years. Loving every moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does it because TFS is useless.  You could however use the "TF.exe" command line to get around some of the limitations of the UI.

The TF.exe command should be under something like the following, so it's probably worth adding this directory to your path.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe

You can then choose a suitable location on your drive, create a new workspace and then get the code at a specific version (or just the latest)

```
C:\my_temp_location> tf.exe workspace /new <workspace_name> /collection:<server_location>
C:\my_temp_location> tf.exe get <source_location> /version:<changeset> /recursive
```

If you want to see a list of workspaces you currently have then you can just run the following command:

```
C:\> tf.exe workspaces
```

Comment: Yep, agreed on useless. How do I specify credentials? Do you have a link to more commands?

Comment: Never mind, I found it: `/login:<domain@user>,<password>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725.aspx

Comment: You can run `tf.exe help` to see a full set of commands or something like `tf.exe help get` to see help for that command.  I feel your pain though, I really hate using this product, having come from using Subversion this feels like a step backwards

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also started with svn on Linux.

Comment: Team Foundation Sidekicks is a nice GUI to do such tasks: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 6):

A straightforward way to do what you 're after, without generating any new workspace, is to:

- [Shelve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) your pending changes into a new shelveset
- Get the specific version you 're looking for & do any reviews
- Get latest once you 're done
- Unshelve your previously shelved changes

Comment: Could be useful, but I cannot, for example, compare the two folder structures or copy missing files.

Comment: I see what you mean. Another way to compare the folder in between different versions, is to (1) select "View History" from the Source Control Explorer, then (2) highlight two different changesets (press Ctrl) and finally (3) right-click to select "Compare..".